# Android Development. webview doesn't disappear ontouchevent

Tags: android, webview, touch

This is my code

```
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    wv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    return true; // Required for receiving subsequent events (ACTION_MOVE, ACTION_UP)
}
```

It doesn't do anything
I want the webview to disappear when the screen is touched. The webview is being used to host a ad.

My activity_main.xml code is:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.catching.apples.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">


<WebView
android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     />
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webbanner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Are you using `FrameLayout`? Some time i have issue with `View` visibility inside `FrameLayout`. I couldn't find the solution, but changed the `Layout` element and it worked.

Comment: How do I change it layout?

Comment: Post the layout file that holds this `WebView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In past, i've got problem with Visibility using `FrameLayout`, so i suggest you to switch to `LinearLayout` to solve this problem.

Changing your layout to:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.catching.apples.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webbanner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Using `wv.setVisibility(View.GONE);`, now i'll work.

And using `layout_height="0dip" and layout_weight="1"`, the `activity_main_webview` will fit all screen except by the `webbanner`.

Comment: Thanks! Ill mark as answer. So your saying I can make it the webview will wrap arounf ad/webbanner?

Comment: With `LinearLayout` the `webbanner` will stay below the `activity_main_webview`.

Comment: Also you can change your FrameLayout into LinearLayout and insert it into FrameLayout as child will work.

Comment: wait. WHat if I want webbanner to display at the top of screen?

Comment: So you must change the order, first webbanner latter main_webview.